# How to use Firebase Auth + Combine to Sign-In and prevent Sign-In

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui, combine

So I've been following Log-In SwiftUI tutorials for Firebase and it's doing what it's supposed to for the most part: An error pops up when one or more of the input fields are left blank.

The problem occurs however, when I fill in the username + password fields with random gibberish. The view changes rather than popping up an error saying that the username is invalid (which I see in my console).

I've done some research and found that the problem might be due to the asynchronous behavior of Firebase and I haven't necessarily connected the error toggle to the sign-In result. But as a noob, I don't know how to implement the trailing closure in my code, and unsure where to go from here.

What change do I need to make exactly to ensure that upon failure of signing in with firebase, the view does not change and error pops up?

Here's my Sign-In function:

```
    func signIn(){
    error = false
    session.signIn(email: user_account, password: password){
        (result, error) in
        if let errornew = error {
            self.inputerror = errornew.localizedDescription
            print("\(String(describing:error))")
            self.error = true
            self.alert.toggle()

        } else {
            self.user_account = ""
            self.password = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Parent View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var session:SessionStore
@State var setUp = false


func getUser(){
    session.listen()
}

    var body: some View {
    Group{
        if(session.session != nil){

            Text("App Home Page")
            Text("Welcome")
            Text("Email: \(session.session?.email ?? "")")
        } else {
            OpeningView() // Sign-In function is in a child view under OpeningView() 
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: self.getUser)
}
```

Session Class:

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject{
@Published var isSetUp:Bool?
var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
var session: User? {didSet {self.didChange.send(self)}}
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

//checks to see whether or not we have a user
func listen(){
    // monitor authentication changes using firebase
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {
            //if we have a user, create a new user model
            print("Got the user: \(user)")
            self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email!)
        } else {
            //if not, then session is nil
            self.session = nil
        }
    })
}
func signUp(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
}

func signIn(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
}

func login(withEmail email: String, password: String, _ callback: ((Error?) ->())? = nil){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){(user, error) in
        if let e = error{
            callback?(e)
            return
        }
        callback?(nil)
        print("Login Successful")
    }
}

func signOut(){
    do{
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.session = nil
    } catch {
        print("Error Signing Out.")
    }
}

func unbind(){
    if let handle = handle {
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }

}

deinit{
    unbind()

   }
```

}

```
struct User {
var uid : String
var email : String?

init(uid: String, email: String?){
    self.uid = uid
    self.email = email
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your View needs something like this on top to check whether you are logged in or not:

```
    var body: some View {

            ZStack {
                if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    // Your View when you are logged in.
else {
SignInView()
} }
```

Comment: I did that in the parent view. Updating to show that code.

Comment: Try FireBase official Auth.auth().currentUser != nil as I have written in my answer. It will still be nil, when the login was unsuccessful. I don't know what your "session" does.

Comment: It goes straight to already logged in with that code.. and no active e-mail shows in the Text(user.email) (which has already proved to work). I'll show you my session as well

Comment: Strange. An easy workaround would be then to check for "if session.session?.email != nil" at the top of your View.

Comment: when you say on top of the view, wouldn't it go as a conditional in an if-statement before invoking signIn()? Or am I missing something here

Comment: I mean to replace it with "if (session.sesson != nil)".